# List linux users

Tags: linux, groups, git

I need to find a group in linux that doesn't appear in my /etc/groups file.

I run the following command and get an error

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git
adduser: The group `git' already exists.
```

Yet when I run the following command, there is no group git

```
cat /etc/group | grep  git
#no results
cat /etc/passwd | grep git
#no results
cat /etc/shaddow |grep git
#no results
```

This is a brand new Ubuntu 12.04 box with no changes except it was tied to LDAP. Haven't even installed vim or git yet.

Why am I getting the error the group git already exists? And is there any way around it? I want to install [gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md).

Answer (score 4):

Check `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, specifically the `groups` line. Also check the output of

`$ getent groups git`

To find out why you get the error about the group already existing.

Reference: `man nsswitch.conf(5)` and `man getent(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding them into this group that it thinks is there

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git git
```

Or

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' --ingroup git git
```

You could also try to delete the group and see what happens

```
groupdel git
```